# make: Command line variable propagation

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If I have two Makefiles as below.

`Makefile`

```
all:
        make -f Makefile.app
```

`Makefile.app`

```
T=1

all:
        @echo $(T)
```

How does `T` get its value specified from command line, as shown below.

```bash
$ make T=10
# make[1]: Entering directory 'xxx'
10
# make[1]: Leaving directory 'xxx'
```

The make being used here is `GNU Make 4.3`.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable specified on the command line is considered an 'override' variable in that it will override any normal assignment in the makefile.   More precisely, the when you assign a variable on the command line, that variable name gets marked with a property of override.  Any normal attempts to assign a value to an override variable will not have any effect.   The override variable will be inherited by a submake as if it were a command line assignment...

You can use the `override` keyword in make to override an overridden variable.  i.e. in your case, if you did

```
override T=1
```

in your makefile.app, then this would cause `T` to have a value of 1.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html for more information on this.